# Create Node contains Field collection with restws + services

Tags: services, entities, 8

I am trying to create a node with RESTFULL api using restws and services modules (latest versions) on Druapl 7 - openpublish destro.
the node contains a Field collection (images field collection field) i was trying to attache the fid returned from the /backbone/rest/files.json [POST] but the field accept nothing

JSON Sample for the field

> "field_op_gallery_image": {
>
> > "und": [
> >
> > > ```
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "3",
> > >    "revision_id": "3"
> > >  },
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "4",
> > >    "revision_id": "4"
> > >  },
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "5",
> > >    "revision_id": "5"
> > >  },
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "6",
> > >    "revision_id": "6"
> > >  },
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "7",
> > >    "revision_id": "7"
> > >  },
> > >  {
> > >    "value": "8",
> > >    "revision_id": "8"
> > >  }
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ]
> > >        },

Can any one help , thanks in advance

Comment: Could you edit the question and include your code please? A JSON dump of the payload you're sending with the request would also be extremely useful

Comment: Done please recheck

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did not fiend any solution :( but the best way to use field with multi value enabled

Comment: Any luck with this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

This sandbox will implement a field_collection service for services 3.x: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/graber/2141747